# Opencart :- How to use different page style in paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, opencart2.x

I have 2 sites (a.com, b.com). So in paypal i have 2 page styles.
1 primary page style is used for a.com which is in magento.

My b.com site is in opencart, which suppose to use 2nd page style which is not primary. Magento 1 style is Primary.

Both site have different logo.

Using Opencart Version Version 2.0.1.1.

I tried to apply `<project path>\catalog\controller\payment\pp_express.php`

```
$data = array(
'METHOD'             => 'SetExpressCheckout',
'PAGE_STYLE' => 'New Style'
);
```

But it's still taking primary. How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Got solution use 'PAGESTYLE'          => 'New Style'. How to close question?

Comment: Add the solution as an answer to your question; about 48 hours from now you'll be able to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use

```
$data = array(
            'METHOD'    => 'SetExpressCheckout',
            'PAGESTYLE' => 'New Style'
        );
```